# Empty views in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

'm having some problems with ViewPager,
I've created a PagerAdapter with following instantiateItem  method

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        View v = in.inflate(R.layout.weeklyoverviewview, null);
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.weeklyoverviewlist);
        WeekAdapter a = new WeekAdapter(cxt, time.plusWeeks(position).getWeekOfWeekyear(), time.plusWeeks(position).getYear());
        lv.setAdapter(a);
        TopNavigatorView nv = (TopNavigatorView) v.findViewById(R.id.weeklyoverviewnavigator);
        nv.setTitle("W" + time.plusWeeks(position).getWeekOfWeekyear() + " - " + time.plusWeeks(position).getYear());
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
        return v;
    }
```

The WeekAdapter looks like

```
 public class WeekAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public ArrayList<View> views;

        public WeekAdapter(Context context, int week, int year) {
            LayoutInflater in = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            views = new ArrayList<View>();
            DateTime d = new DateTime().withYear(year).withWeekOfWeekyear(week);
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                View v = in.inflate(R.layout.weeklyoverviewlisttitle, null);
                TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.weeklytitletext);
                t.setText(d.withDayOfWeek(i + 1).dayOfWeek().getAsText() + ", " + d.withDayOfWeek(i + 1).monthOfYear().getAsText() + " "
                        + d.withDayOfWeek(i + 1).getDayOfMonth() + ", " + d.withDayOfWeek(i + 1).getYear());
                views.add(v);
            }
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return views.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return views.get(arg0);
        }

        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return views.get(arg0).getId();
        }

        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            return views.get(arg0);
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the first 3 pages see that is instantiated directly seems to be correct but when i swipe to another views i've got 7 items in the listview BUT the text is empty.
When i check the text in the textview with log i see that the text is set correctly but i't don't appears.

Edit: Like this,
http://i50.tinypic.com/108e8ac.png , cant show as image couse reputation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, but no idea what so ever why it's working.
I changed the ListView's height to fill_parent instead of wrap_content